# How to configure GraphQL or ApolloClient to be able to execute queries with introspective fragments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to execute GraphQL query like this:

```
fragments.js
-----------------------------------------------------

import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const CORPORATE_MANAGER_ROLE = gql`
  fragment CorporateManagerRole on UserRole {
    id
    name
    corporationId
    corporationName
}
`;
```

```
listUser.js
--------------------------------------------------------

import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { CORPORATE_MANAGER_ROLE } from './fragments';

const ListUserQuery = gql`
    ${CORPORATE_MANAGER_ROLE}
query ListUser($input: GetUserListInputData!) {
  listUser(inputData: $input) {
    items {
      firstName
      lastName
      email
      status
      comments
      birthDay
      gender
      id
      initials
      roles {
        ... on CorporateManagerRole {
          id
          name
          corporationId
          corporationName
        }
      }
    }
      }
  }
`;

export default ListUserQuery;
```

But I don't get response with data in useEffect inside React component.
I have "apollo-client": "2.6.4"

```
usersList.jsx
--------------------------------------------------------------

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Table, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow, withStyles, withTheme,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { withSnackbar } from 'notistack';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import InputBase from '@mui/material/InputBase';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './styles';
import MaterialNavButton from '../../components/MaterialButton/materialNavButton';
import useQueryCustomApolloClient from '../../hooks/useQueryCustomApolloClient';
import ListUserQuery from '../../graphQL/User/ListUser';


const UsersList = ({
  classes,
  theme,
  enqueueSnackbar,
}) => {
  const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);
  console.log(usersList);

  const {
    loading: usersLoading,
    error: usersError,
    data: usersData,
  } = useQueryCustomApolloClient(
    ListUserQuery, {
      variables: {
        input: {
          corporationId: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  );
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (usersError !== undefined) {
      enqueueSnackbar(usersError.message, {
        variant: 'error',
      });
    }
    if (!usersData) return;
    debugger;                 <----- application don't stop here even after succesfull response data which I see in Chrome devtools network logs

    setUsersList(usersData.listUser.items);
  }, [usersData]);

...

return (<div>
   usersList.map(item => ...)
</div>)
```

P.S. Added component code where I'm trying to get users list by using GraphQL query.
So, usually when I don't use peace of query like this "... on CorporateManagerRole {...}" I catch answer in useEffect hook, but in this case I don't get it in useEffect.

I

Comment: What do you mean by "*introspective fragments*"? I see no introspection in the code you've shown.

Comment: "*I don't get response with data*" - what happens instead? Do you get an error, is the data empty? Is the problem only with the roles? How are you using `useEffect`? Please show your code. Why are you using `useEffect` instead of `useQuery` in react? Pleas also show how you are creating the `ApolloClient`, i.e. how you are configuring your links.

Comment: @Bergi Please, take a look again, I added some info in my post.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an error anywhere?

Comment: It's not quite clear whether you are trying to spread a named fragment or trying to use an inline fragment.

Comment: @Bergi You are right, now I see an error: message: "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'corporationName' in type 'UserRole' is undefined @ 'CorporateManagerRole/corporationName'"    message: "Validation error of type UnusedFragment: Unused fragment CorporateManagerRole"

Comment: But before I added  following code: "export const CORPORATE_MANAGER_ROLE = gql`
  fragment CorporateManagerRole on UserRole {
    id
    name
    corporationId
    corporationName
}
`;  There was no error in graphql query, just didn't catch the data in useEffect hook